# How can I change to a different iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I ran the installation of Xcode 6.1.1 and iOS 8.1. I wanted a different one so I went to (Xcode >> Preferences >> Downloads) and installed iOS 7.1 Simulator. It worked fine while I'm in the project, but when I removed the project and run another project, it's running with iOS 8.1. iOS is already installed, I couldn't change it back!

[image]

Help?

Comment: Why don t you use the latest XCode version ? It may solve your pb.

Comment: Can I use it with iOS 7.1?

Comment: I don t have XCode in front of my eyes, but IOS version list has version you need. Give it a try.

Comment: @Setra if you're talking about simulator than you can use only 8.1+ with the latest XCode (v. 7.2) on El Capitan and 7.1+ on Yosemite

Comment: Then I need time and I'll msg you, thank you :)

Comment: @Oleshko that means I should be with the one I have.